# Curl (php script) downloads incomplete file

Tags: php, curl, download

I am using a php script in order to download an xml file from an external url using curl, but I am encountering a problem. Curl sometimes fails to download the complete file. The problem happens even more often when I run the script through my host server using cron.

This is the script:

```
<?php
header('Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8');

//initialize downloading xml file tries
$xml_dl_attempts = 0;

//set filename of output xml file
$findex = 0;
while(file_exists("xml".$findex.".xml"))
{
    $findex++;
}
$filename = "xml".$findex.".xml";

//filname for log file
$logfilename = "log.txt";

//Open (append) logfile for write.
$logfileout = fopen($logfilename, 'a');
fwrite($logfileout, "Starting attempts to download the xml file at ".date("H:i:s Y-m-d")."\r\n");

//Attempt to download xml file 8 times
do {
    //Sleep 3 second before retrying download
    if($xml_dl_attempts > 0 ) sleep(3);

    //Increse number of download attempts
    $xml_dl_attempts++;
    //Write to logfile
    fwrite($logfileout, date("H:i:s Y-m-d").": Download attempt number ".$xml_dl_attempts.": ");

    //Download xml file using curl
    $ch = curl_init();
    $url = 'http://www.opap.gr/web/services/rs/betting/availableBetGames/sport/program/4100/0/sport-1.xml?localeId=el_GR';

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    set_time_limit(300); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);

    $outfile = fopen($filename, 'w');
    if (!$outfile)
    {
    exit;
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $outfile);

    if(curl_exec($ch)==false)
    {
        fwrite($logfileout, "curl_error: ".curl_error($ch));
    }
    fclose($outfile);
    curl_close($ch);

    //Clear errors
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    libxml_clear_errors();

    //Parse xml file
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($filename);

    //Check for errors
    if($err = libxml_get_last_error())
    {
        fwrite($logfileout, "failed\r\n");
    }
} while($err !== false && $xml_dl_attempts < 8); //repeat if xml was not completely downloaded

//Check if 
if(!$err)
{
    fwrite($logfileout, "successfull\r\n");
}
fwrite($logfileout, "End.\r\n");
fclose($logfileout);
?>
```

As you can see I check if simplexml parser gives an error while parsing the downloaded xml file. If an error occurs then I repeat the process, with limit of 8 attempts. I also created a log file.

Here is the log file for a whole day:

```
Starting attempts to download the xml file at 18:35:00 2012-09-25

18:35:00 2012-09-25: Download attempt number : failed

18:35:03 2012-09-25: Download attempt number : failed

18:35:07 2012-09-25: Download attempt number : successfull

End.

Starting attempts to download the xml file at 19:35:00 2012-09-25

19:35:00 2012-09-25: Download attempt number 1: failed

19:35:03 2012-09-25: Download attempt number 2: failed

19:35:06 2012-09-25: Download attempt number 3: failed

19:35:10 2012-09-25: Download attempt number 4: failed

19:35:13 2012-09-25: Download attempt number 5: failed

19:35:16 2012-09-25: Download attempt number 6: failed

19:35:20 2012-09-25: Download attempt number 7: failed

19:35:23 2012-09-25: Download attempt number 8: successfull

End.

Starting attempts to download the xml file at 20:35:00 2012-09-25

20:35:00 2012-09-25: Download attempt number 1: failed

20:35:04 2012-09-25: Download attempt number 2: failed

20:35:08 2012-09-25: Download attempt number 3: successfull

End.

Starting attempts to download the xml file at 21:35:00 2012-09-25

21:35:00 2012-09-25: Download attempt number 1: failed

21:35:04 2012-09-25: Download attempt number 2: failed

21:35:07 2012-09-25: Download attempt number 3: failed

21:35:11 2012-09-25: Download attempt number 4: successfull

End.

Starting attempts to download the xml file at 22:35:00 2012-09-25

22:35:00 2012-09-25: Download attempt number 1: failed

22:35:04 2012-09-25: Download attempt number 2: failed

22:35:07 2012-09-25: Download attempt number 3: successfull

End.

Starting attempts to download the xml file at 23:35:00 2012-09-25

23:35:00 2012-09-25: Download attempt number 1: failed

23:35:03 2012-09-25: Download attempt number 2: failed

23:35:07 2012-09-25: Download attempt number 3: failed

23:35:10 2012-09-25: Download attempt number 4: failed

23:35:14 2012-09-25: Download attempt number 5: failed

23:35:17 2012-09-25: Download attempt number 6: failed

23:35:21 2012-09-25: Download attempt number 7: successfull

End.

Starting attempts to download the xml file at 00:35:00 2012-09-26

00:35:00 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 1: successfull

End.

Starting attempts to download the xml file at 01:35:00 2012-09-26

01:35:00 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 1: failed

01:35:04 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 2: failed

01:35:07 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 3: failed

01:35:11 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 4: failed

01:35:14 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 5: failed

01:35:18 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 6: failed

01:35:21 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 7: failed

01:35:30 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 8: failed

End.

Starting attempts to download the xml file at 02:35:00 2012-09-26

02:35:00 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 1: failed

02:35:03 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 2: failed

02:35:07 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 3: failed

02:35:10 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 4: failed

02:35:13 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 5: failed

02:35:17 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 6: failed

02:35:20 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 7: failed

02:35:24 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 8: failed

End.

Starting attempts to download the xml file at 03:35:00 2012-09-26

03:35:00 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 1: failed

03:35:04 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 2: failed

03:35:07 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 3: failed

03:35:10 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 4: failed

03:35:14 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 5: failed

03:35:17 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 6: failed

03:35:21 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 7: failed

03:35:30 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 8: failed

End.

Starting attempts to download the xml file at 04:35:00 2012-09-26

04:35:00 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 1: failed

04:35:03 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 2: failed

04:35:07 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 3: failed

04:35:10 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 4: failed

04:35:14 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 5: failed

04:35:17 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 6: failed

04:35:21 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 7: failed

04:35:24 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 8: successfull

End.

Starting attempts to download the xml file at 05:35:00 2012-09-26

05:35:00 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 1: failed

05:35:04 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 2: failed

05:35:08 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 3: failed

05:35:11 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 4: failed

05:35:15 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 5: failed

05:35:18 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 6: failed

05:35:22 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 7: failed

05:35:25 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 8: failed

End.

Starting attempts to download the xml file at 06:35:00 2012-09-26

06:35:00 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 1: failed

06:35:03 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 2: failed

06:35:07 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 3: failed

06:35:10 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 4: failed

06:35:14 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 5: failed

06:35:17 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 6: failed

06:35:21 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 7: failed

06:35:24 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 8: failed

End.

Starting attempts to download the xml file at 07:35:00 2012-09-26

07:35:00 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 1: failed

07:35:04 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 2: failed

07:35:07 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 3: failed

07:35:11 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 4: failed

07:35:14 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 5: failed

07:35:18 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 6: failed

07:35:21 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 7: failed

07:35:24 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 8: failed

End.

Starting attempts to download the xml file at 08:35:00 2012-09-26

08:35:00 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 1: failed

08:35:03 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 2: failed

08:35:06 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 3: failed

08:35:10 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 4: failed

08:35:13 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 5: failed

08:35:16 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 6: failed

08:35:20 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 7: failed

08:35:23 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 8: failed

End.

Starting attempts to download the xml file at 09:35:00 2012-09-26

09:35:00 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 1: failed

09:35:04 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 2: failed

09:35:07 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 3: successfull

End.

Starting attempts to download the xml file at 10:35:00 2012-09-26

10:35:00 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 1: failed

10:35:03 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 2: failed

10:35:06 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 3: failed

10:35:10 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 4: failed

10:35:13 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 5: failed

10:35:17 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 6: failed

10:35:20 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 7: successfull

End.

Starting attempts to download the xml file at 11:35:00 2012-09-26

11:35:00 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 1: failed

11:35:03 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 2: failed

11:35:07 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 3: successfull

End.

Starting attempts to download the xml file at 12:35:00 2012-09-26

12:35:00 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 1: failed

12:35:04 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 2: failed

12:35:07 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 3: failed

12:35:11 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 4: failed

12:35:14 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 5: failed

12:35:17 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 6: failed

12:35:21 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 7: successfull

End.

Starting attempts to download the xml file at 13:35:00 2012-09-26

13:35:00 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 1: failed

13:35:03 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 2: successfull

End.

Starting attempts to download the xml file at 14:35:00 2012-09-26

14:35:00 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 1: failed

14:35:03 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 2: failed

14:35:07 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 3: failed

14:35:10 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 4: successfull

End.

Starting attempts to download the xml file at 15:35:00 2012-09-26

15:35:00 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 1: failed

15:35:03 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 2: failed

15:35:07 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 3: failed

15:35:10 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 4: failed

15:35:13 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 5: failed

15:35:17 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 6: failed

15:35:20 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 7: failed

15:35:24 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 8: failed

End.

Starting attempts to download the xml file at 16:35:00 2012-09-26

16:35:00 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 1: failed

16:35:03 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 2: failed

16:35:07 2012-09-26: Download attempt number 3: successfull

End.
```

The thing is that sometimes it manages to get the complete file after some attempts, other times fails completely. Another thing to pay attention is that the curl_exec doesn't return an error when the xml is incomplete.

Unfortunately the server that has the xml doesn't support range, so I cannot just resume the file when it is incompletely. I could increase the limit of attempts, let's say to 50, but the thing is that in a failed attempt the script still downloads some data, so for an 1MB xml file, if it fails 30 times downloading 500KB per time, it would have downloaded 16 MB of data for a successfull attempt. I want to run this script every hour, so I believe this is going to hurt my server's bandwidth.

Why curl fails to download the complete file. Are there some options so that I make it behave like a browser, who eventually always gets the file?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried longer timeouts?

Comment: @MattS perhaps that's not the issue. Check the timestamps.

Comment: The size of the xml varies between a few KB and 2 MB. As for the timeout, I have already set it to 300 seconds, and each attempt is being made afte a few seconds (and that because of a 3 second sleep()). Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your source: the server.

I tried running your scraper on [`scraperwiki`](http://scraperwiki.com) and here is what it shows:

[image: 1st screenshot]

Also, same problem occured when I personally tried loading the xml and it worked for me the third time.

You can see the server is closing the connection in the following pic's first two requests and not the third (successful one).

[image: 2nd screenshot]

So, the problem is with the server, and you can do nothing about it if it ain't yours.
(except of-course bringing this to them server-admins notice!)

Note: I believe scraperwiki has really good internet connection since it is relied upon by many. So, you can safely blame it as [server fault](https://serverfault.com/) #jboss

Comment: I was afraid that this is the case. Unfortunately I can't do anything about it. The only think that was bugging me is that when I run the script from my localhost it has by far more chances to get the file successfully and in first attempt, but when running the script from my host server it does worse by far. Is there anything tha may be causing this difference in my host server?

Comment: internet connection might be it. but, i have no idea. seriously.